# Determine command line arguments a program uses to launch another one?

Tags: linux, bash, process, command-line-arguments

*Motivation*: When I run `grub-mkrescue`, it internally launches `xorriso` to write an iso file. I want to see what command line arguments `xorriso` is being passed. I know I could check the sources of `grub-mkrescue`, but I'm interested in a generic solution now. I tried with `strace` but the output didn't tell.

```
strace grub-mkrescue -o foo.iso iso/
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: could you write the complete line? take into account that xorriso takes less than 1 second to finish

Comment: `ps -fC xorriso` while it is running.

Comment: Typically, most programs have a "verbose" option for more detailed output. Try running grub-mkrescue with  -v or --verbose. Maybe even -V.

Comment: It would fork before execve, so you won't see it with strace unless you use `-f` to follow children

Comment: @thatotherguy yours is the correct answer, post it as such so I can mark this question as resolved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A process will fork before running `execve`, so it will not show up in the strace of the parent.

Use `strace -f` to also follow children.

Comment: calling it with `strace -f grub-mkrescue -o foo.iso iso/ | grep xorriso` did the trick perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace xorriso with a more verbose one:

```
which xorisso
cd $(dirname $(which ps))
mv xorisso xorisso.org
test -f xorisso | echo "mv failed, stop here" 

cat <<'@' > xorisso
echo "$0 $@" > /tmp/xorisso_call.tmp
"$0.org" "$@"
@
chmod +x xorisso
```